# Multiple timeline animation in javafx-8

Tags: animation, javafx-8, timeline

There are lots of ImagePanels on a Region surface. I keep them in Groups. They are supposed to scroll in a chain horizontally.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFVO.jpg)

There are some methods I wrote for this to work.
E.g. switching position on the left.
(rects - rectangles. earlier it was rectangles).

```
//---------     OO<->OO   OOOOOO   OOOO        -----------------------
  private void shiftAnimatedInLeft(ObservableList rects)
  {
    ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
    {
      double startPosition = ((ImagePanel) rects.get(i)).getTranslateX();
      double finishPosition = -(rects
              .size() - i) * getSideImageOffset() - getCenterOffset() - (IMAGE_WIDTH * (1 - SCALE_SMALL) / 2);
      Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
  timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
          new KeyFrame(new Duration(0),
                       new KeyValue(((ImagePanel) rects.get(i)).translateXProperty(),
                                    startPosition,
                                    INTERPOLATOR)),
          new KeyFrame(new Duration(500),
                       new KeyValue(((ImagePanel) rects.get(i)).translateXProperty(),
                                    finishPosition,
                                    INTERPOLATOR))
  );
  pt.getChildren().add(timeline);
//      timeline.play();
    }
    pt.play();
  }
```

E.g. shift elements from center to the left.

```
//---------     OOOO   <-OOOOOO   OOOO        -----------------------


private void shiftAnimatedCenterToLeft(ImagePanel rect)
  {
    double startPosition = rect.getTranslateX();
    double finishPosition = - getSideImageOffset() - getCenterOffset() - (IMAGE_WIDTH*(1-SCALE_SMALL)/2);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
        new KeyFrame(new Duration(0),
                     new KeyValue(rect.translateXProperty(), startPosition, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.scaleXProperty(), rect.getScaleX(), INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.scaleYProperty(), rect.getScaleY(), INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.angle, -270.0, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.opacity, 1.0, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.vboxStyle, "imagePanelBlackVBox", INTERPOLATOR)),
        new KeyFrame(new Duration(500),
                     new KeyValue(rect.translateXProperty(), finishPosition, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.scaleXProperty(), SCALE_SMALL, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.scaleYProperty(), SCALE_SMALL, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.angle, ANGLE, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.opacity, 0.0, INTERPOLATOR),
                     new KeyValue(rect.vboxStyle, "imagePanelWhiteVBox", INTERPOLATOR))
);
timeline.play();
  }
```

etc.

These methods use onKeyPressed (left\right) or mouse wheel scroll events.

Finally, **problem:** if i try using this in an independent application it works normally (but not nice). However if i'm trying to integrate it into another app, it all gets really laggy and slows overall animation.

Answer (score 0):

You could run animation in another thread with Platform.runLater()- maybe it would help- or test performance of your application with profiler like JProfiler(or any other free equivalent) and optimize the most demanding parts of your code.

Comment: No. Very bad idea! Don't use other threads for animations! `Timeline` is absolutely fine for that.